# How do I count inside a dataframe using unique values and conditional?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take this `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'client_id':[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'key':['0_382','0_382','0_356','1_365',float('nan'),'1_365',float('nan'),'2_284','2_405'],
                   'operation':['buy','sell','sell','buy','transfer','buy','fee','buy','buy']})
```

```
   client_id    key operation
0          0  0_382       buy
1          0  0_382      sell
2          0  0_356      sell
3          1  1_365       buy
4          1    NaN  transfer
5          1  1_365       buy
6          2    NaN       fee
7          2  2_284       buy
8          2  2_405       buy
```

I need to create a column named `pos_id` that will give an incremental value (1,2,3...) for each row, for unique values of `client_id` and `key`, and using a conditional to skip `transfer` and `fee` values of `operation`.

The result should be like this:

```
   client_id    key operation pos_id
0          0  0_382       buy      1
1          0  0_382      sell      1
2          0  0_356      sell      2
3          1  1_365       buy      1
4          1    NaN  transfer    NaN
5          1  1_365       buy      1
6          2    NaN       fee    NaN
7          2  2_284       buy      1
8          2  2_405       buy      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways.

The first method groups `['client_id', 'key']` to the same `'pos_id'` within `'client_id'` regardless of whether or not they appear consecutively.

Use `where` to mask the rows you want to ignore and then `groupby` + `ngroup` with `sort=False` will count the unique combinations. Then subtract off the min within each group to get the counter starting at 1.

```
s = (df.where(~df['operation'].isin(['transfer', 'fee']))
       .groupby(['client_id', 'key'], sort=False).ngroup()
       .replace(-1, np.NaN))  # ngroup makes NaN group keys -1.

df['pos_id'] = s - s.groupby(df['client_id']).transform('min') + 1
```

---

This method requires the input sorted on at least `'client_id'` and then will only group the same key if they are consecutive into the same `'pos_id'`. Remove the rows you want to ignore, then check for differences in each row and take the `cumsum` within `'client_id'`

```
s = (df.where(~df['operation'].isin(['transfer', 'fee']))
       .dropna(how='all'))

s = s['key'].ne(s['key'].shift()) | s['client_id'].ne(s['client_id'].shift())
df['pos_id'] = s.groupby(df['client_id']).cumsum()
```

---

For your input either results in:

```
   client_id    key operation  pos_id
0          0  0_382       buy     1.0
1          0  0_382      sell     1.0
2          0  0_356      sell     2.0
3          1  1_365       buy     1.0
4          1    NaN  transfer     NaN
5          1  1_365       buy     1.0
6          2    NaN       fee     NaN
7          2  2_284       buy     1.0
8          2  2_405       buy     2.0
```